# Updating an Evernote Note from HTML

Tags: c#, evernote

Using the C# SDK I'm working on a simple application to load a note from evernote, allow the user to edit the note using a HTML wysiwyg editor and then save it back to Evernote.

I'm a little confused. I can load a `ENNote` from the standard `ENSession` and access the HTML version of the note, but to update I have to load a `Edam.Type.Note` which has no HTML properties to set just the standard XML doc.

I can see there is a `ENHTMLtoENMLConverter` class but its internal? Its counterpart `ENMLtoHTMLConverter` is public.

Is there an easy to convert basic HTML/ENHTML into a `Edam.Type.Note` so I can update without writing my own converter or compiling my own version of the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

> ### Creating a note using HTML or web content
>
> The SDK contains a facility for supplying HTML or web content to a
>   note.
>
> ```
> ENNote myFancyNote = new ENNote();
> myFancyNote.Title = "My first note";
> myFancyNote.Content = ENNoteContent.NoteContentWithSanitizedHTML("<p>Hello, world - <i>this</i> is a <b>fancy</b> note.</p>");
> ENNoteRef myFancyNoteRef = ENSession.SharedSession.UploadNote(myFancyNote, null);
> ```
>
> This method handles general HTML content, including external style
>   sheets which it will automatically inline. Please note that this is
>   not a comprehensive "web clipper", though, and isn't designed to work
>   fully on all arbitrary pages from the internet. It will work best on
>   pages which have been generally designed for the purpose of being
>   captured as note content.

Source : [Getting Started with the Evernote Cloud SDK for Windows](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-windows/blob/master/Getting_Started.md#creating-a-note-using-html-or-web-content)

Comment: That's for creating a new note. I wish to update a note. There is no update method on the the ENSharedSession under EnSession. Only under the ENSessionAdvanced which requires a Note not an ENNote. If I try and get the content using ENNoteContent.NoteContentWithSanitizedHTML, it doesn't expose any methods to get the ENML content (everything is internal)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without dipping into the "advanced" stuff. You still want to call `ENSession.SharedSession.UploadNote` but use the version that lets you specify one of the "replace" policies as appropriate:

```
public ENNoteRef UploadNote(ENNote note, ENSession.UploadPolicy policy, ENNotebook notebook, ENNoteRef noteToReplace)
```

You'll still need to create an `ENNote` with your updated content (you can use the `NoteContentWithSanitizedHTML` etc). And supply the note ref pointing to the original note you want to replace.